# Como fazer select count(*) com Python e mysql.connector

Tags: mysql, python

A biblioteca que estou usando é [essa](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html).

Esse é o código:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tabela as t WHERE ... """, (v1, v2))

for (total) in cur:
    if total > 0:
        print('Existe')
```

O problema é que nunca existe valor.

PS: Existem dados na tabela para trazer um `count > 0`

O que está errado nisso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como é um count você não precisa usar o `for` para pegar os dados.

Outra coisa é que o total não é um inteiro, ele é um [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

De qualquer forma faz assim:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tabela as t WHERE ... """, (v1, v2))
(total,) = cursor.fetchone()
if total:
    ...
```